# How do I set struts 1.0 Form class members using Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, struts-1

I have a struts 1.0 form bean, and I'm trying to test custom validation.

The form bean makes explicit reference to its class members, i.e., when validating an email address, the call looks like this:

```
  @Override
  public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request)
  {
    ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
    Validator validator = ESAPI.validator();

    try
    {
      email = validator.getValidInput("AuthorizedPayerEmailAddr", email, "Email", Email.MAX_ADDRESS_SIZE, true);
    }catch(Exception e){ doStuff() }
```

In my test class, I have attempted to tell Mockito to call real methods for setters and getters:

```
  AddAuthorizedPayerForm form = Mockito.mock(AddAuthorizedPayerForm.class);    
  Mockito.doAnswer(Answers.CALLS_REAL_METHODS.get()).when(form).getEmail();
  Mockito.doAnswer(new CallsRealMethods()).when(form).setEmail(Mockito.anyString());
```

This technique has resulted in my form class members not being set.

The only way I've gotten this to work is by mocking the getter

`when(form.getEmail()).thenReturn(emailString);`

and then changing the form class to access its fields through the method like this:

```
      email = validator.getValidInput("AuthorizedPayerEmailAddr", getEmail(), "Email", Email.MAX_ADDRESS_SIZE, true);
```

Which is exactly what I *don't* want to do!  I don't want to alter my form logic just to make it testable.

Additional Context:  There are some abstract methods that set form state at runtime in the context of a user session.  I know this is bad design (form bean should JUST be a form bean) but I can't fix that.  This application does not use *any* dep injection so I need this form to be mocked for *everything* BUT the `validate()` method and the form fields its validating.

Comment: Could you just put setters on the form (thus not changing the getter logic) and just set the variables on the form object directly as part of you test setup?

Comment: Mockito closes that door.  Since I'm starting out with a mocked instance, calls to any setter/getter pairs are hand-waved away without touching the actual code.

Comment: Surely you aren't mocking the form object as that's what you are testing?  If you mock it how can you test it? *I thin I'm missing something*

Comment: I want all the methods/fields on my form class to be mocked, EXCEPT the calls to my setter/getter and the call to the `validate()` method.  As I dig through the documentation, its looking like I need to use a `spy`.